# How do I add these numbers from a text file together?

Tags: python, list, text

I have a file of numbers that are organized in different lines.

I've been working on this since 8 this morning and I keep running into the same two problems:

1. when I try to split the file by line, I can't do any math because it's a list
2. when I don't split them up, nothing can happen because there is '\n' all over the file because there are multiple lines.

The file looks like this:

```
6 7 3 7 35 677
202 394 23 

595 2 30 9
39 3 5 1 99
```

I basically want to add up all the numbers per line. So I want to add 6,7,3,7,35,677 together and so on. But the lines in the two "paragraphs" need to stay together.

This makes the most sense to me but it doesn't work.

```
filename = input('Enter filename: ')
f = open(filename, 'r')
data = f.read().split()
my = (int(data[0]))
text = (int(data[1]))
sum(my,text)
```

I have no idea what's going on. I know i need to split('\n') but then I can't do any math. I can't convert to int either. Any advice?

Comment: You probably want split on spaces: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split then convert all the elements in the resulting list to `int`

Comment: Please clarify: Which one of these are you looking for: (1) row totals, (2) "paragraph" totals, (3) the net total.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as objFile:
    lsNos = objFile.readLines()

total = 0
for strLine in lsNos:
   if strLine.strip():
      lsNos = strLine.split(" ")
      for No in lsNos:
        if No.strip():
          total += int(No.strip())
```

Comment: I got this message when I tried that. "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'" I've gotten this for pretty much everything I've tried unfortunately.

Comment: This answer has the right idea, you do have to split on a line (as you've mentioned), but then you also need to do a second split on the spaces in order to extract each number. Do this for each line, adding the split numbers together and you have your totals. In order to keep the top two lines separated from the bottom two, you could use a counter, or use the fact there is a blank line in the text file between them,

Comment: I've been doing that and I keep getting this: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'". How do I get around this?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/testfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    words = lines.split(' ')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Are you using my edited code ? I don't think so. I haven't used any variable named words and lines.

Comment: I changed the variables to work with what I already had in my code, but yes I used what you advised.

Comment: Just try to print the value of lines in your code before words = lines.split(' ')

Answer (score 0):

Once you split, you need to convert the "text" type str or Unicode to integer, float, or decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import imap


with open("your_file") as inp:
    for numbers in (imap(int, line.strip().split()) for line in inp):
            print(sum(numbers)) if numbers else print()
```

If you're on Python 3, remove the import line and replace `imap` with `map`

Comment: While this method might be shorter, the user asked a beginner's question and a simple, clear solution is best. (They may not use or understand lambda functions or imap etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines might help.

```
filename = input('Enter filename: ')

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        # split line into a list of numbers (as strings)
        line = line.split()

        if not line:
            # If the line is empty, print a blank line
            print()
        else:
            # otherwise get the total for the line
            total = 0
            for n in line:
                total += int(n)

            print(total)
```

Comment: If you open a file without the `with` statement, make some effort to close it.

Comment: Fair enough. I've added a `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want

```
filename = input('Enter filename: ')
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip():
            total = sum(int(i) for i in line.split())
            print(total)
        else:
            print() # print new line if line is empty
#Output
735
619
636
147
```